# Prove that there is a real number $a$ such that $\frac{1}{3} \leq \{ a^n \} \leq \frac{2}{3}$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$

Tags: contest-math

Prove that there is a real number $a$ such that $\frac{1}{3} \leq \{ a^n \} \leq \frac{2}{3}$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$ Here, $\{ x \}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

My attempt: Clearly $a$ cannot be an integer because $\{ a^n \}=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also $a$ cannot be a rational number because $\{ x \}$ is the same as $a$ modulo $1$. So the fractional part of $a$, at some point, will be less than $\frac{1}{3}$.

I try to find irrational $a$ which satisfies the inequality but I got no luck.

Can anyone give some hint to this question?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that it is true?

Comment: It seems unlikely.  Even with $\phi \approx 1.618$ you have $\phi^2=\phi+1$ but it breaks down for $\phi^3 \approx 4.236$

Comment: For what it's worth, $\sqrt{\frac{58}9}$ (found by trial and error) works for $1\le n\le 7$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I have a feeling that it may not be true. However, I have no proof to counter it.

Comment: Do you need $\le$ or can it be $\lt$? That may help proving with induction, creating a new $a$ when $n+1$ is the first violation.

Comment: @Pieter21, isn't it obvious?

Comment: You use the tag (contest-math) and since people have some doubts about the fact you're trying to prove : please give us a reference of this problem. Where did you find it? What contest? Which year?

Comment: @Jesse, indeed it is obvious, since $a$ isn't rational, it is more of an inspirational remark.

Comment: I would guess that the proof of [Mills' constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) might be useful here (assuming you can find it, **and** understand it).

Comment: @Pieter21, what you just said sparked this idea, if its strict inequality, I don't know if its useful: (above) $\iff \frac{1}{3}\times10<(last\ digit\ of\ \lfloor a^n\times10\rfloor)<\frac{2}{3}\times10$. Something tells me this may be useful, fact that we have tools to finds the last digit of a number!

Comment: Your proof about rationals is not true and there must be a rational number with that property...

Comment: This is chapter 1, problem 3.8 of "Selected Problems in Real Analysis". The solution is given on pages 153-154: books.google.com/books?id=WMs97jhcwS4C&pg=PA153

Comment: I don't see how you proof with rationals works; $a$ mod $1$ and $\{a\}$ are the same regardless of whether $a$ is rational. It seems like you're suggesting that since $\{a\}^n$ is eventually less than $\frac{1}3$, then so is $\{a^n\}$, but this is clearly not the case in general.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There exists $\alpha \in\left[\dfrac{16}{3},\dfrac{17}{3}\right]$ with the required property. To see this, we will construct an interval sequence
$$\left[\dfrac{16}{3},\dfrac{17}{3}\right]=[\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}]\supset [\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}]\supset\cdots\supset[\alpha_{n},\beta_{n}],$$
where $\alpha_{n}$ and $\beta_{n}$ are such that
$$\alpha^n_{n}-\dfrac{1}{3}=\beta^n_{n}-\dfrac{2}{3}=m_{n}\in \Bbb N^{+},$$
so that, for any $x\in [\alpha_{n},\beta_{n}]$, we have
$$\dfrac{1}{3}\le\{x^n\}\le\dfrac{2}{3}.$$

We construct the interval sequence by induction. Assume that we have $[\alpha_{n},\beta_{n}]$. Let
$$a=\alpha^{n+1}_{n},\quad\quad b=\beta^{n+1}_{n}.$$It follows that $$ 
b-a=(m_{n}+\dfrac{2}{3})\beta_{n}-(m_{n}+\dfrac{1}{3})\alpha_{n}>\dfrac{\alpha_{n}}{3}>\dfrac{5}{3}.$$
Then there exists $m_{n+1}\in \Bbb N^{+}$ such that
$$\left[m_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{3},m_{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{3}\right]\subset[a,b].$$
We take
$$\alpha_{n+1}=\sqrt[n+1]{m_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{3}},\qquad\beta_{n+1}=\sqrt[n+1]{m_{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}}.$$
Now $$\alpha^{n+1}_{n}=a<\alpha^{n+1}_{n+1}=m_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{3}<\beta^{n+1}_{n+1}=m_{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{3}<b=\beta^{n+1}_{n},$$and hence $\alpha_{n}\le\alpha_{n+1}<\beta_{n+1}<\beta_{n},$ or
$$[\alpha_{n},\beta_{n}]\supset[\alpha_{n+1},\beta_{n+1}].$$

Comment: In your statement $$[m_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{3},m_{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{3}]\supset[a,b],$$ Should the $\supset$ sign be reversed?

Comment: ok,I have edit it.

Comment: A very intuitive solution. Thanks.

Comment: Implementing the algorithm on a computer leads to the result $\alpha \approx 5.62144865272$.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously it depends how approximately a≈5.62144865272, but a quick check with windows calculator shows that a^14 ≈ 31468458796.31579.. or a^15 ≈ 176898325303.72424... for instance

Comment: Yeah, but just adjusting the final $2$ to a $3$ due to rounding, by $a^{14}$ that corresponds to a difference of $0.78370$, and for $a^{15}$ it's $4.720$, so it really does require more decimal places by then.